# update object properties with new data that fetch from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to update object properties with new data that fetch from MongoDB. The following code not work. I don't know why? Anyone can help me?

```
 var UserDB = require('../models/user_model.js').UserModel;    
    function User(uid, username, credit, socket, seat, normal, bank, bankThree) {
            this.uid = uid;
            this.username = username;
            this.credit = credit;
            this.socket = socket;
            this.seat = seat;
            this.normal = normal;
            this.bank = bank;
            this.bankThree = bankThree;
            this.serverPerform = 0;
            this.actionTaken = false;
            this.cards = [];
            this.bet = 0;
            this.catched = false;
            this.action = false;
        }
        User.prototype.update = function(){
            var self = this;
            UserDB.findOne({uid:this.uid},function(err,doc){
                console.log(doc);
                if(!err){
                    self.username = doc.username;
                    self.credit = doc.credit; 
                    console.log(self); // work as expected
                }
            });

            console.log(self); // nothing change
        };
    var user = new User(1);
    user.update(); //nothing change
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your mongo update function is ASYNCHRONOUS, so of course your log inside the callback works, and the one outside doesn't.

```
User.prototype.update = function(callback){ //Now we've got a callback being passed!
    var self = this;
    UserDB.findOne({uid:this.uid},function(err,doc){
        console.log(doc);
        if(!err){
            self.username = doc.username;
            self.credit = doc.credit; 
            console.log(self); // work as expected
            callback(); //pass data in if you need
        }
    });
};
```

Now that you've passed a `callback` in, you can use it like so:

```
var user = new User(1);
user.update(function() {
    //do stuff with an anonymous func
});
```

Or define your callback and pass it in

```
function callback() {
    //do stuff
}

var user = new User(1);
user.update(callback);
```